# What does the "Actually, It Was A Dog" Hangover do?

Tags: wasted

The explanation states:

> You have a 1% chance that any non-boss, enemy humanoid you attack was
>   actually just a dog.

I have encountered this booze a few times already but didn't have the nerve to try this. Could someone explain me what this actually do ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Based on the fact that this is an adult swim game, my best guess would be that it's just a gag drink to make you feel bad for killing an enemy then finding out it was just a puppy.

Comment: Idk, so far every drink had some kind of effect, and dogs are quite vicious in this game.

Comment: It is possible that, as it's a hangover, it refers to "Hair of the dog", a term used to describe drink that you have in order to lessen a hangover. You can read more about the term [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_of_the_dog) on wikipedia and also [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-hair-of-the-dog) if you prefer a non open source of information